# How can i get state from a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can i get state of the class from a function?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
Platform,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,
TextInput,
TouchableOpacity,
Alert
} from 'react-native';

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state={
        telephone: '',
        password: ''
    }
    this.onLogin=this.onLogin.bind(this);

}
render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text style={styles.title} >Login</Text>
         <View style={styles.form}>
            <TextInput onChange={(e) => this.setState({telephone: 
            e.target.value})}
            value={this.state.telefon} keyboardType='numeric' maxLength={9} 
            returnKeyType='next' underlineColorAndroid="#BAAC9A" style=
            {styles.telinput} placeholder="Telephone"></TextInput>
            <TextInput onChange={(e)=>{this.setState({password: 
            e.target.value})}}
            value={this.state.password} style={styles.passinput}  
            secureTextEntry returnKeyType='send'   placeholder="Password">
            </TextInput>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttoncontainer} onPress=
        {this.onLogin} >
            <Text style={styles.buttontext}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.subtext}>Not registered?</Text>
    </View>
)
}

onLogin() {
var {telephone, password} = this.state;
alert('telephone='+ encodeURIComponent(telephone)+'&password='+ 
encodeURIComponent(password));
}
}
..styles
```

In alertbox i'm getting *telephone=undefined&password=undefined*.
I also tried to make onLogin arrow function (without binding in constructor), and alert is not even showing..
The question is **how to get state in onLogin function** (without Redux) and why alert isn't working with arrow function

Answer (score 0):

In your code I see you are using `TextInput` with e.target.value

> ```
> <TextInput onChange={(e) => this.setState({telephone: 
>   e.target.value})}
> ```

Using event.target.value makes sense for the web platform.

The official documentation https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html says to use the TextInput like this. There is no event.target.value.

```
<TextInput
  onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
  value={this.state.text}
/>
```

Comment: it's bugged with secureTextEntry, and it's not the answer to my question..

Comment: I have updated my answer. I clarified the specific issue which is usage of `e.target.value`

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to access a change event in your `onChange` handler and read the value from `e.target.value`. While this works in the browser, you're working in a native space in React Native and don't have access to the traditional React `SyntheticEvent`. Instead, the `<TextInput />` component from the API exposes `text` as the value passed to the `onChangeText` method. This is equivalent to `e.target.value` in the browser, just a different implementation under the hood. Change your `setState` calls to look like this:

```
<TextInput onChangeText={(text)=>{this.setState({password: text})}} />;
```

This should update your `state` accordingly and you should be able to access it in `onLogin`.

With respect to using an arrow function for `onLogin`, you need to have a specific `babel` configuration for Class properties transform (this feature is still in Stage 2). This plugin should do the trick: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/

Answer (score 0):

I see some minor errors on your code, and I quickly wrote a working example on Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/a-simple-login-form

Check that through whether there are some differences compared to your code.